# Replace with ignore case sensitive

Tags: java, android, regex, string-formatting

I need to replace `$achieved$` from a string and it should be case insensitive. Because sometimes in string from server we get `$ACHIeved$`, hence it should ignore case sensitive. I am using below code.

```
stringWithoutFormating.replace(Constant.PROGRAM_DETAILS_ENTRY_CONTENT_FIELDS.achieved, String.valueOf(achieved));
```

I have tried with `(?i)` as well but its not working.
Can it be done with regex, if yes what should be the regex?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `replace` performs literal string replacement,  and does not accept a regex as its first argument. You need to use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll`. Next, `$` is a special regex char (it matches end of string), so it must be escaped. You may use `Pattern.quote` for that. So, you may use

```
stringWithoutFormating = stringWithoutFormating.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(Constant.PROGRAM_DETAILS_ENTRY_CONTENT_FIELDS.achieved), String.valueOf(achieved).replace("$", "\\$"));
```

Here, `(?i)` will make the search case insensitive, `Pattern.quote(Constant.PROGRAM_DETAILS_ENTRY_CONTENT_FIELDS.achieved)` will turn `$achieved$` into `\$achieved\$`, and then the replacement will take place. The `.replace("$", "\\$")` performed on the replacement is necessary to escape literal `$` in the replacement.